# GANs: What does the pdf of the sample data p(x) mean?

Tags: density-function, gan

In the context of GANs, the concept of a probability distribution comes up as the generator tries to emulate the "distribution" of the data: $p_{data}(x)$.

For me, the use of "distribution" here seems a little fuzzy.
How should one interpret what $p_{data}(x)$ means, say for GANs operating on the MNIST dataset, where each pixel value in a given $28 \times 28$ image is normalized to fall within [0,1]?

Comment: I think this is a horse of a different color. More akin to conditional probability than a pdf. Consider that if we ask if an image is the letter 'G' we generate a probability of its being so, but not a pdf. In short, and in so far as I am understanding this, it seems to be pattern recognition using extracted but uncharacterized traits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model each individual pixel $x_i$ as a random variable with distribution $p(x_i)$. You could also consider the whole image as a random variable $x$ with distribution $p(x)$. Their distributions are related by

$$p(x_i) = \int p(x)\ d x_{j \neq i}$$

Pixel values are usually treated as continuous for GANs, but for other classes of generative models (for example, autoregressive models), they are typically treated as discrete, ranging from 0 to 255.

Almost all real numbers are uncomputable, so no, you can't "limit storage of pixel values to a finite number of bits".

$p_{\text{data}}(x)$ is typically continuous when pixel values are treated as continuous, and vice versa.

> although strictly speaking computers do not have infinite resolution and are therefore only approximating pdfs with pmfs.

Not necessarily -- "infinite" objects can be precisely represented with finite space. For example, I can represent a standard normal distribution with just two integers, $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful. I'm now interpreting $p(x)$ as the joint probability distribution of 784 random variables: ie $p(x) = p(x_1, x_2, ...x_{784})$ Then, to determine the marginal pdf of a particular pixel $p(x_i)$, we simply integrate over the other 783 dimensions. For example, if x were a 3 pixel image then $p(x_1) = \int \int p(x_1, x_2, x_3) dx_2 dx_3$

Comment: Please let me know if my understanding of your solution is correct.

Comment: @colmor that's right... however you should be aware that for GANs, $p(x) = \int p(x|z) p(z) dz$ is not really tractable to compute.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to shimao's nice answer, I want to emphasize that interpretation #1 is just wrong. In MNIST images, pixels are not independent. Any generator will have to mimic this dependence in order to produce a collection of synthetic hand-written digits.